# How to get beamer-style bibliography (with icons) when using article class and natbib?

Tags: beamer, bibliographies, natbib, marginpar, article

I am writing a document in article class, using natbib, and would like to produce a bibliography with icons in the left-hand margin, which illustrate the type of resource being listed.  After some Googling, I've seen that some Beamer-style bibliographies have this option, and I like the beamer-style icons fine.

Is there any way to get a Beamer-style bibliography, or any bibliography with such icons in the margins (perhaps using something like marginpar), when using article class with natbib?  If not, is there any way to do so in article class, using something other than natbib, like biblatex?

Comment: Could you provide some information about *which* beamer-style bibliography styles you have in mind? Presumably, there's more than on such style. By the way, if you already have the beamer .bst file, you should be able to use it in documents of class `article` just as well as as in documents of class `beamer`.

Comment: @Mico, it's my understanding that these icons are a feature of the standard bibliography in beamer.  See slides 35--36, [here](http://www.stat.ubc.ca/~ruben/data/Stat302_2011/Sample-beamer.pdf).  I've not used beamer myself to have tried out any specific styles.

Answer (score 3):

It is easy to do in `biblatex` using `\marginpar`.

A possible way is to use the `begentry` hook to call `\marginpar` and the `\ifentrytype` conditionals to control what to put in the margin.

Here is a basic structure to do that.

```
\renewbibmacro{begentry}{%
  \marginpar{%
    \ifentrytype{article}
      {ARTICLE}
      {\ifentrytype{book}{BOOK}{OTHER}}}%
}
```

By default if you use a one-side layout, the marginals are in the right margin to put on the left you have to use `\reversemarginpar` before using them.

For the icons, use `\includegraphics` or any other way to include them instead of the `ARTICLE/BOOK/OTHER...` placeholders.

Comment: Thank you @Guido!  May I also ask how it's done in biblatex?  (Of if that information is elsewhere, just give me a pointer.)  I'm considering making the change to biblatex in the near future.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm getting an error that "\renewbibmacro{begentry}" is an undefined control sequence.

Comment: The solution I provided is for `biblatex`. You have to load `biblatex` with `\usepackage{biblatex}` (and often many options)